# Functions which are undefined at a point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What can we say about undefined values when we encounter them? Is it possible to have a variable with an undefined value? Or do we perhaps just say it is meaningless to talk about $f$ at a point $a$ if $f(a)$ is undefined?

If I have a partial function $f$ for which $f(x)$ is undefined at a particular $x$, we can limit the domain, but still this doesn't help us explain whether we can talk about $f(x)$ at this point, Can we somehow limit the variable space such that $x$ cannot have a value like this?

Is there any concept of equality for undefined values, for example does $undefined = undefined$?

Is it that we would say 'when $x=0$, $y$ has a value that is meaningless, so we cannot talk about either $y$ or $f(x)$?

Say we have some variable $y$ and $y=f(x)$, when $f(x)$ is not defined can $y$ have any value, Or does it just not make any sense to talk about $y$ at all?

Comment: You can add some value which you call "undefined" to co-domain of $f$, like $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ if $x\neq 0$, $f(x)={\rm undefined}$ if $x=0$, then $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{{\rm undefined}\}$.

Comment: This is not special to math. For example if one says X is a round square. If a phrase involves a definite description having no denotation, some say the phrase is ungrammatical, others just let it denote an arbitrary extra constant in the vocabulary involved.

Comment: About two undefined: let $f(x)=1/(x^2-1)$ if $x\neq \pm 1$, $f(1)={\rm undefined}_+$, $f(-1)={\rm undefined}_-\neq {\rm undefined}_+$, then $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{{\rm undefined}_+,{\rm undefined}_-\}$. Or we can set that $f(1)=f(-1)={\rm undefined}$. Then there are no two undefined but one.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu but this is if we define it as part of the function? where 'undefined' is sort of an 'imaginary' constant that we've come up with? Obviously, in the typical use of 'undefined' we can't really use an equals?

Comment: If your definition of "undefined" is the same as "does not exist", then we cannot compare it, because we cannot compare something that does not exist. In this case we should exclude $a$ from domain of $f$. However if your definition of "undefined" is "has value out of prescribed set", then we can compare it with other quantity of the same nature. In this case we should include $f(a)$ in co-domain of $f$.

Answer (score 5):

Well if we have a function $f:X\to Y$, then we **cannot** talk about $f(a)$ if $a\notin X$, because we haven't defined what that means, and there is no way to "guess" what it could be, as we could extent $f$ to include $a$ and define $f(a)$ to be whatever we would like.

Now this does not mean it's not meaningful to consider points outside the domain of a function. Indeed there are a lot of cases where we can extend a function with a natural choice of extension so that the function fulfills certain properties. Let's look at an example.

Consider the function

$$f:[0,2]\setminus\{1\}\to\mathbb{R},\quad x\mapsto x^2.$$

The way we have defined it, $f(1)$ is undefined, as it is not in the domain we have given $f$, and indeed we could extend it to be whatever we want there however a very useful property we often care about is continuity, so we might ask, is there a way to define $f(1)$ so that $f$ is *continuous* there? Simply adding this new requirement of a property we care about gives us a unique value for what we should define $f(1)$ to be, as

$$\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=1,$$

meaning we should define

$$f(1)=1$$

to get continuity. Now this might seem like a very contrived example where it's obvious what we should define it as, however there are situations where it's not so obvious, for example if we're given something like

$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},$$

and want to know what a reasonable choice of $f(0,0)$ is. Of course continuity is not the only property we might be interested in, but it shows you how we some times have natural useful choices of how to extend functions, even though there is no canonical answer.

So to summarize: if $f$ is undefined at $a$, then $f(a)$ is meaningless, however there are still meaningful ways one can *define* $f(a)$ to have desired properties.

**EDIT:**

As a remark that can be important to bring up when talking about this, as pointed out by @user3716267, we are *technically* defining a *new function* when we extend the value, as the domain is a part of the function. Indeed for clarity, we could write that we take our original function $f:X\to Y$, and from it define a new function $\hat{f}:X\cup \{a\}\to Y\cup\{\hat{f}(a)\}$ where we have that $\hat{f}|_X=f$, and $\hat{f}(a)$ is our choice for the extension. This is rarely ever done explicitly in practice, however, and authors usually just redefine the function so that $f$ becomes what we have written here as $\hat{f}$.

Comment: Say we have some variable $y$ and $y=f(x)$, when $f(x)$ is not defined can $y$ have any value I decide? Or does it just not make any sense to talk about $y$ at all? Or can I define that $y=f(x)$ only for $X$ where $X$ is the domain of $f$? In which case how do we then define $y$? Does $y=f(x)$ become a conditional equation as opposed to some definite relationship? Usually when we define dependence the relation has to hold generally. I know this is something that's not generally well defined, but whats your best guess?

Comment: @Lorago it might help to modify your post a bit to notate the extended function as $f'$ rather than $f$, since the domain of $f$ is fixed unless we re-define $f$ entirely.

Comment: @user3716267: I think it is quite OK to re-define $f$ entirely. I have read some books that keep doing that throughout 

Comment: @String It's appropriate to do so when you can be confident that the audience won't be confused by the mercurial definition of $f$.  In this case, the OP is *explicitly* confused about this, so it is better to be a bit more verbose and add the extra clarity.

Comment: @user37577 I think you are still somewhat confused.  When we say $y = f(x)$, what we mean is that there is some function $f$ and some element $x$ in the domain of $f$, and if we apply $f$ to $x$ we get some other element $y$ in the codomain of $f$.  If $x$ is not in the domain of $f$, then this is (formally) nonsense and our expression fails to refer to anything in particular.  It may, however, be possible (per the post above) to extend our definition of $f$ in a natural/useful way to recover a sensible interpretation - but this is talking about a different function!

Comment: @user3716267 Thanks for the feedback, I added it as a remark at the end

Comment: @user3716267: You might be correct. I think it is difficult to tell.

Comment: Does $y=f(x)$ have to hold for all $x$, is that why the expression is meaningless, because if $x$ is not in the domain it makes no sense? Could I define X to be the set of $(y,x)$ where $x$ is in $D$ the domain of $f$ and have $y=f(x)$ for all $(y,x)$ in $X$? Then $y$ could be anything when $f$ is undefined? Or am I talking nonsense?

Comment: @user37577 Almost.  The traditional "formal" definition of a function is a set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$, such that $x$ takes values in the domain of the function and $y$ takes values in the codomain.  We say $y = f(x)$ when the tuple $(x,y)$ exists in the function.  If $x$ is not in the domain of $f$, then there is no such tuple with $x$ as the first element and $f(x)$ therefore doesn't "point" to anything at all.

Comment: Talking about the function outside of the domain is either wrong because $x$ cannot really take the value, otherwise I have to conclude, $y=f(x)$ only hold for a subset of the total $(x,y)$ that are possible, namely the ones whose pairs are in the domain/codomain of $f$? Any values outside of the domain of $f$ this relation doesn't hold, and in theory $y$ can be anything, is this an okay way to view it? Essentially I want to be able to answer, if given $y=f(x)$ and $x$ is outside of the domain, what is $y$?

Comment: @user37577 The answer to your last question is that $y$ is not necessarily *anything* in that situation.  Until we give it a definition, it doesn't refer.  There are many more strings of symbols we can write than there are valid arrangements of mathematical objects per our axioms.  I think you are getting caught up on notation a little bit - if we write $y = f(x)$ then we really mean that $y$ and $f(x)$ are symbols that point to the *same* mathematical object.  If there is no such mathematical object being pointed to, then *both* symbols fail to refer.

Comment: @user3716267 I have also attempted answering the question. I think your last interaction here did clarify a lot!

Answer (score 3):

After reading your question and interactions in comments, this is what I understood you to be interested in:

> We have some function $f:X\to Y$ and a relation $y=f(x)$ where $x,y$ are variables. When $x\notin X$, then what is $y$ and $f(x)$? How can we think about them?

If this is your question, then first we need to clarify what is meant by:

1. Function
2. Relation

A function can be defined in various ways, but a helpful way to see it is that given $x$ in the domain, $f(x)$ picks out a specific fixed element in the codomain.

The relation $y=f(x)$ expresses the relation that $(x,y)$ is a pair in the domain/codomain such that given $x$, then $y$ is the specific fixed element in the codomain that the function $f$ designates as $f(x)$.

---

Given those definitions, and considering $x\notin X$, then what is $y$ and $f(x)$? And in what sense is the relation $y=f(x)$ fulfilled?

Well, when $x\notin X$ then $f(x)$ is not defined. It is merely notation at that point, not pointing to a value/element in $Y$. Since $y$ was merely defined via the relation $y=f(x)$, this variable suffers the same lack of definition as $f(x)$ does at this point.

Only difference being that $y$ is a variable, and $f(x)$ is an expression. Both are symbols used to refer to something given other conditions. But their values are equally undefined for this situation.

In some sense $y=f(x)$ could still be considered to be in play, in that we used it to understand that since $f(x)$ is not defined, then $y$ is also not defined.

---

**FINAL REMARK**: The relation $y=f(x)$ would be easier to understand, if we could use directed notation, to illustrate that the relation is not merely an equality but has to be used in a certain sequence of steps:
$$
x\overset{f}{\longmapsto} f(x)\implies y
$$
so that if the first arrow successfully produces a value, then this value is propagated as the value of the variable $y$. Since this is the only way $y$ is defined to attain a value, it will otherwise remain undefined.

Comment: In the case when you define $y=f(x)$ and say '$y=f(x)$ is still in play' is that equivalent to saying that $y=f(x)$ for all $(x,y)$? So even though $x$ is outside of the domain we are trying to have this relation?

Comment: @user37577: The relation has a direction, namely evaluate $f(x)$, then you have $y$. So the reason $y$ has no value for $x$ outside the domain is precisely since $f(x)$ cannot be evaluated. In that sense they are linked. Not by value, but by relation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its a difficult kind of question because you are not explained this kind of stuff that much and it's not a well defined thing.

Comment: @user37577: Cool! You asked a difficult and abstract question, I think! user3716267 helped clarifying what you were asking, and you persisted to finally make sense of it. Good on you!